# Hibernate Reverse Engineering Create Set (Composite Key)

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, reverse-engineering, composite-key

I'm having trouble getting Hibernate to correctly reverse engineer a MySQL database into a Java Class.

I have 3 tables:

- departments (pk = dept_no)
- employees (pk = emp_no)
- dept_emp (composite pks dept_no and emp_no)

I am trying to modify the Hibernate Reverse Engineering file to force the DeptEmp Java class that is generated to link a single department to a set of employees within that department, but I keep getting the same error, even though I have declared a name attribute for the set:

```
org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not configure overrides from file: C:\lib\workspace\Hibernate Analysis 2\resources\hibernate.reveng.xml
Could not configure overrides from file: C:\lib\workspace\Hibernate Analysis 2\resources\hibernate.reveng.xml
org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not configure overrides from file: C:\lib\workspace\Hibernate Analysis 2\resources\hibernate.reveng.xml
Could not configure overrides from file: C:\lib\workspace\Hibernate Analysis 2\resources\hibernate.reveng.xml
org.hibernate.MappingException: invalid override definition
invalid override definition
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 10; columnNumber: 88; Attribute "name" must be declared for element type "set".
Attribute "name" must be declared for element type "set".
```

My Reverse Engineering File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-reverse-engineering PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Reverse Engineering DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-reverse-engineering-3.0.dtd" >

<hibernate-reverse-engineering>
    <table-filter match-catalog="employees" match-name="departments" />
    <table-filter match-catalog="employees" match-name="employees" />
    <table-filter match-catalog="employees" match-name="dept_emp" />

    <table name="dept_emp" class="com.DeptEmp">
        <set name="employeesSet" table="employees" inverse="true" lazy="true" fetch="select">
            <key>
                <column name="dept_no" ></column>
            </key>
            <one-to-many class="com.Employees"></one-to-many>
        </set>
    </table>
</hibernate-reverse-engineering>
```

My Hibernate Config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/employees</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">****</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">****</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
        <property name="hibernate.default_catalog">employees</property>
        <property name="connection.pool_size">20</property>
        <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>
        <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider</property>
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        <property name="format_sql">true</property>
        <property name="use_sql_comments">true</property>

    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Comment: Did you manage to make this work?